# Do reports called from a main report require a Shared Data Source?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS in SQL Server 2008 R2.  It consists of a main report and a second report that is opened via a hyperlinked column using Text Box Properties > Action.  Both reports are in the same solution.  The second report opens as it should when applying a Shared Data Source reference.  However, when it applies a Data Source using an Embedded connection instead, then the following error appears when running the main report and selecting the hyperlink that would normally open the second report.

> An error occurred during local report processing. An error has
>   occurred during report processing. Cannot create a connectio to data
>   source 'XXXX'. You have specified integrated security or credentials
>   in the connection string for the data source, but the data source is
>   configured to use a different credential type.  To use the values in
>   the connection string, you must configure the unattended report
>   processing account for the report server.

If it were not for the project requirements specifyign not to apply Shared Data Sources, this would not be an issue.  Whether or not the main report is using Shared or embedded data sources, makes no difference with regard to the above error taking place.  The main report works regardless.

So, my question is whether Shared Data Sources are required when a main form is calling a sub form in the same solution?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if additional details are required.

Answer (score 0):

Is the second report (the hyperlinked report) part of the same overall solution in Visual Studio?  If so, you should be able to link to it.

You can try adding the 2nd report to the same solution as the first report.  You may have to delete the shared data source reference on the 2nd report, save, and re-add it.

I had this happen to me quite a bit, and while it always gave me fits in Visual Studio, it would work fine when published to the test or production report server.

Comment: Yes, both reports are part of the same overall solution.  They are being developed in BIDS.  I'll give your suggestion a try and let you know if it works.  Thanks!